# How work with parked domain names in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have PHP web site based on Codeigniter and the same domain names parked to this hosting account and engine.

Problem is that Codeigniter is configured on only one domain name in file `config.php`.
When I open other parked domain name then is running redirection on domain by default, and I see URL not which I opened site.

How I can configure Codeigniter for parked domain names? That web site will work from some domain names?

Comment: Parked domain names are just that....parked. They're not active and cannot be accessed as you would for an active domain.

Comment: Sorry, I have available domain names

Comment: Do you mean addon domains?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the config for the `base_url` by catching the domain the user came to.

```
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

However, are you sure the redirection is done by Codeigniter and not a the Server level or htaccess file?